# Animating frame resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to animate the re-sizing of a frame in html?

I have a webpage where there a are two frames horizontally stacked (say 500px, remaining). Upon click of a 'minimize' image, the frame to the left is shrunk to around 100px. Is it possible to animate this shrinking via jquery/javascript/css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are seeking to animate inner frames then I would go with Dr Molle's answer. If, however you are seeking to animate a frameset, you will have to do it manually. The example below illustrates. To examine it, you 'd better use a local web server to avoid problems with cross - domain restrictions (at least in Chrome, haven't tested it anywhere else...).

#### frame1.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        frame 1
        <br />
        <a href='#' class='minimize'>Minimize</a>

        <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(function () { 
                $('.minimize').click(function (evt) {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    window.parent.minimize();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### frame2.html

```
<html><body>frame 2</body></html>
```

#### frameset.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(function () { 
                var minimizeInterval = null;
                var current = 500;
                var pace = 15;
                var stop = 100;

                window.minimize = function () {
                    minimizeInterval = setInterval(function () {
                    console.log('minimizing...');
                        $('frameset').attr('cols', current + ',*');
                        current -= pace;
                        if (current < stop) 
                            clearInterval(minimizeInterval);
                    }, 10);
                };
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <frameset cols="500,*">
        <frame id='frame1' src="frame1.html"></frame>
        <frame id='frame2' src="frame2.html"></frame>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('#frameselector').animate({width:100});
```

Comment: currently using this script to minimize : `window.parent.document.all.topframe.cols = '500,*';`. Can you please say how can I fit this in the animate method. Script inside the html of the frame page to be minimized

Comment: This script is not suitable for minimizing regular frames. Check my answer.

Comment: @Ioannis Karadimas : Yes, of course you're right. I didn't thought that anybody still uses native frames.

Comment: @Playmaker: See the suggestion by Ioannis Karadimas

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. But yeah i am (unfortunately) using native frames. It would be shame of me (or anyone who knows existence of JQuery) to ask for something as simple as the animate method suggested by you, without googling it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can animate most css properties.

Here's [a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/Vaz98/) : when you click on the left frame the right one is animated and reduces in size.

This is done using :

```
$('#a').click(function(){
    $('#b').animate({
        height: '50px'
    }, 5000);
});​
```

Comment: thanks mate, but I do know about it and its easy using divs. as i mentioned I need help animating 'frames' (don't ask why I am using frames. Too far to change it now.)