# How to change frame height from another frame in frameset with javascript

Tags: jquery, frames, frameset

I have a frameset:

```
<frameset rows="30px,*">
    <frame id="frame1" src="frame1source.html">
    <frame id="frame2" src="frame2source.html">
</frameset>
```

I need to be able to change the height of #frame2 from within #frame1 using jquery.

I tried many solutions to no avail, including:

```
$(window.parent.frames[0].document).css("height",300);
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok I solved this using pure JS by resizing the frameset, not just one frame.

```
parent.document.getElementsByTagName( 'frameset' )[ 0 ].rows="300,*";
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#frame2").css("height",300);
This works for you ?

Comment: I am working with [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381576/animating-frame-resizing). But this also worked: `parent.document.getElementsByTagName( 'frameset' )[ 0 ].rows="300,*";`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below tag :

```
$("#fromdate, #todate").click(function () {
        $('frameset', top.document).eq(2).attr('rows', '300,*');
    });
```